# How can I simulate a 150MHz crystal oscillator in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, crystal, oscillation

I am trying to simulate a 150MHz crystal in LTspice, but I don't get any oscillation out of it. I have an equivalent circuit of a 32MHz crystal, even with that I don't get anything out of it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Kick it. One way is to make V1 a 4V step at t=0 instead of a DC supply.

Comment: Simulating a crystal oscillator is always an issue as the LC tank in a crystal has an **extremely high quality factor** (like 100000 or higher) meaning that it is very difficult (it takes a lot of time) to increase or decrease the energy in the LC tank. That means **extremely long simulation times**. Personally I use a trick, I decrease the Q of the LC tank by increasing the C value and decreasing the L value by a certain factor (like 1000) so that the Q is decreased so the oscillator needs less time to start up.

Comment: Indeed as Brian suggests you need to "kick it into action", that means putting some energy in the LC tank to get it going. I prefer to do that by adding a (pulsed) current source in parallel with L1.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie No offense, could u help me understand why you are adding a currnet source instead of voltage source ?

Answer (score 2):

The comments from the other posters are critical to getting any oscillator to simulate but I also question your choice of components.

The BC547 has rather a low FT for 150MHz oscillation. Its worst case is 150MHz with a typical of 300MHz - this is too low.

Your values for C3 and C4 seem much too large - I would expect values of ~22pF.

Lastly, although it may be a 150MHz crystal it is more likely to be a 30Mhz crystal intended to be operated at the 5th overtone - in order to achieve that it is common to include a tuned circuit in the oscillator to direct which overtone to operate at. The crystal will tend to operate at any odd overtone so the gain of the amplifier at frequencies other than the intended one need to be suppressed.

[image]

As the frequency of operation of a crystal is raised the physical thickness required becomes smaller. It is normally impractical to grind a crystal for operation above 30-50Mhz as they become too fragile. To sidestep this overtone operation is used.

[Crysal Oscillator Fundamentals](https://www.edn.com/crystal-oscillator-fundamentals-and-operation-part-iv/)